# Rails - Importing User Email Address Books from (Y!, Gmail, etc...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Lots of sites these days allow users to import their email address book to invite/find friends.

Are there any good rails gems/plugins that offer this ability, accessing gmail/y! APIs etc?

thanks

Comment: Check this http://www.plaxo.com/api/widget . I am using this address book import widget from plaxo across my projects. Its hassle free to integrate and easy to maintain . This is non rails so I am suggesting this as a comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with [contacts gem](https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts)

Answer (score 0):

You can try OmniContacts https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts